# Printing variables of type int excluding functions

Tags: java, token, tokenize

I'm writing a program that reads a code from a file, line by line, and prints whatever is after "int".

For instance:

```
int x;
int y;
```

It prints out:

```
x
y
```

Here's the code that I've written so far

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\example.txt"));

String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);

    while(token.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String s = null;
        s = token.nextToken();

        if(s.equals("int"))
        {
            System.out.println(token.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to exclude functions of type int to be printed, like the "MyFunction" in this example

```
x 
z
MyFunction(int
y)
x,
y
```

Input file:

```
int x = 137;
int z = 42;
int MyFunction(int x, int y) {
   printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x, y, z);
   {
      int x, z;
      z = y;
      x = z;
      {
        int y = x;
        {
          printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x, y, z);
        }
        printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x, y, z);
      }
      printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x, y, z);
    }
 }
```

I'm fairly new to java, so please be patient.

Comment: Giving a complete input file could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Will only work for similar input like the one above.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);

   while(token.hasMoreTokens())
   {
     String s = null;
     String r = null;
     s = token.nextToken();

     if(token.hasMoreTokens()){  //if s was not last token get next one
        r = token.nextToken();
    }
    if(s.equals("int") && r != null && r.length()<3) 
    {
        System.out.println(r.substring(0, 1)); // just to print x instead of x,
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this will work, but only for variable which name is one char long. And it will fail if you have method like `int a( int x, int y)` (note the space before the first parameter). An improvement would be not to check for `r` length but instead check if it's followed by a `(` (using regex) and remove the last character only if it's a comma

Comment: Your code is definitely an improvement on mine, but what if I want to also print the x and y in the **MyFunction** parameters? And in line 6  "int x, z;" I also want to print out the z since it's also been declared as an int.

Answer (score 0):

you may also try this.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String cleaned = line.trim(); //remove leading and trailing white space 
        String [] parts = cleaned.split(" |\\(");// split using white space or opening brace            
        if (line.matches("(\\s*)int(\\s*)(\\w+)(,\\s*\\w+)*(;)")){ // check for multiple variable declariation e.g. int a,b,c;
            for (int k = 1; k <parts.length; k++){
                System.out.println(parts[k]);                            
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i <parts.length-1; i=i+2){
                if((parts[i].equals("int")&&parts[i+1].length()<3) ){ //requires variable name length to be one
                    System.out.println(parts[i+1].substring(0, 1));
                }                            
            }                       
        }                
    }
```